An ETF based (or electronically tradable) structured instrument which behaves like a mortgage
I will keep my question extremely succinct. Very succinctly, for a mortgage you put a deposit, you get a loan, and you pay interest on that loan for N years until your principal (say M) is paid and you gain possession of the property.
I see one specific advantage of such a mechanism : one is able to guarantee that after N years, you will be owning a property of value M (with the assumption that housing prices are non-decreasing). Also, one will also carry the capital gains of any appreciation of the value of the property (again, based on a consequence of our assumption).
Is one able to set up a similar structured option/derivative/swap or anything from finance to somehow “behave” similar to a mortgage (i.e. I buy it with a deposit, pay instalments on it, and receive a possibly appreciated asset some time later).

I'm not sure why that doesn't simply translate to long-term investment, or, if you want more safety at the risk of less growth, bank accounts.

Are you just describing a margin loan?  You put in a fraction of the value of the shares you want, you get a loan for the rest, you pay interest on the loan and if you eventually pay the loan back, you own all the shares you originally bought.  Which have hopefully appreciated (of course, assuming that real estate or shares always appreciate is a good way to be very unpleasantly surprised).

Margin loan is what you're looking for.

Think you are right. Margin Loan is very close to what I was referring to. For example, if you use it to buy a fixed income product, its equivalent of buying a house on mortgage, renting the house, and using the rent of the house as mortgage payments.
